# Error running Object Detection training in google ML engine - grpc epoll fd: 3

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to train Object Detection model with gcloud ml-engine,reference to the official documents https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md，and set runtime-version=1.4，and reference this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2739 to modify the setup.py , but have the error:

> worker-replica-3
>   2018-01-09 06:32:39.416080: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX

ker-replica-3
grpc epoll fd: 3

> 

```
{
insertId: "1fwigqcg5k37j2o"
jsonPayload: {
created: 1515479559.41658
levelname: "ERROR"
lineno: 1051
message: " grpc epoll fd: 3"
pathname: "ev_epoll1_linux.c"
thread: 917
}
```

The last error message is：

> 

```
The replica master 0 ran out-of-memory and exited with a non-zero status of 247.
```

I start the training job on Cloud ML Engine using the following command:

> 

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training object_detection_training_date +%s \
--job-dir=gs://mybucket/train \
--packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
--module-name object_detection.train \
--region asia-east1 \
--config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
-- \
--train_dir=gs://mybucket/train \
--pipeline_config_path=gs://mybucket/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config \
--runtime-version 1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Only runtime version 1.2 is supported currently. We are working on other versions.

Comment: Thank you @Guoqing Xu, I hope you soon support Tensorflow> = 1.4, I always thought I have the wrong code or wrong configuration environment！

Comment: How to switch to 1.2? Is the model repository of git clone code base to downgrade to version 1.2? and the local Tensorflow is  to downgrade to version 1.2 to setup.py? or as long as the runtime is set to 1.2?

Comment: In cloud, you can simply set runtime-version as 1.2 in your job request. If you want to run your job locally as well, then you need to downgrade TF to 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

FYI that log message is not an ERROR. It was downgraded to INFO log in grpc code base last August.